# Debugging C++ code of an R package with Rcpp using gdb cannot print variable value with R_PV (unknown return type)

Tags: c++, r, debugging, gdb, rcpp

I have used RStudio on Ubuntu 18.04 to create an hello world R package using Rcpp like described here in [Rcpp Package Development](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200486088-Using-Rcpp-with-RStudio):

My `~/.R/Makevars` contain only the line

```
CXXFLAGS=-g -O0 -Wall
```

and during pkg build I can see that these flags are applied.

How can print the current value of an R vector (C++ classes `CharacterVector` or `NumericVector` in `gdb` after hitting a breakpoint?

`(gdb) p R_PV(x)` (as explained in [Writing R Extensions](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Inspecting-R-objects)) shows an error (perhaps because the SEXP is wrapped?):

[image]

```
(gdb) whatis x
type = Rcpp::CharacterVector
```

My debug session:

```
R -d gdb --vanilla
(gdb) run
library(RcppTestPkg)
# type Strg + X to break into gdb to set a breakpoint
(gdb) break rcpp_hello_world.cpp:8
(gdb) cont
rcpp_hello_world()
Breakpoint 1, rcpp_hello_world () at rcpp_hello_world.cpp:8
8       NumericVector y   = NumericVector::create( 0.0, 1.0 ) ;
(gdb) n
9       List z            = List::create( x, y ) ;
(gdb) n
11      return z ;
(gdb) info locals
x = {<Rcpp::PreserveStorage<Rcpp::Vector<16, Rcpp::PreserveStorage> >> = {
    data = 0x5555562c4360}, <Rcpp::SlotProxyPolicy<Rcpp::Vector<16, Rcpp::PreserveStorage> >> = {<No data fields>}, <Rcpp::AttributeProxyPolicy<Rcpp::Vector<16, Rcpp::PreserveStorage> >> = {<No data fields>}, <Rcpp::NamesProxyPolicy<Rcpp::Vector<16, Rcpp::PreserveStorage> >> = {<No data fields>}, <Rcpp::RObjectMethods<Rcpp::Vector<16, Rcpp::PreserveStorage> >> = {<No data fields>}, <Rcpp::VectorBase<16, true, Rcpp::Vector<16, Rcpp::PreserveStorage> >> = {<Rcpp::traits::expands_to_logical__impl<16>> = {<No data fields>}, <No data fields>}, cache = {
    p = 0x7fffffffba10}}
y = {<Rcpp::PreserveStorage<Rcpp::Vector<14, Rcpp::PreserveStorage> >> = {
    data = 0x5555562c43d0}, <Rcpp::SlotProxyPolicy<Rcpp::Vector<14, Rcpp::PreserveStorage> >> = {<No data fields>}, <Rcpp::AttributeProxyPolicy<Rcpp::Vector<14, Rcpp::PreserveStorage> >> = {<No data fields>}, <Rcpp::NamesProxyPolicy<Rcpp::Vector<14, Rcpp::PreserveStorage> >> = {<No data fields>}, <Rcpp::RObjectMethods<Rcpp::Vector<14, Rcpp::PreserveStorage> >> = {<No data fields>}, <Rcpp::VectorBase<14, true, Rcpp::Vector<14, Rcpp::PreserveStorage> >> = {<Rcpp::traits::expands_to_logical__impl<14>> = {<No data fields>}, <No data fields>}, cache = {
    start = 0x5555562c43f8}}
z = {<Rcpp::PreserveStorage<Rcpp::Vector<19, Rcpp::PreserveStorage> >> = {
    data = 0x5555562c4440}, <Rcpp::SlotProxyPolicy<Rcpp::Vector<19, Rcpp::PreserveStorage> >> = {<No data fields>}, <Rcpp::AttributeProxyPolicy<Rcpp::Vector<19, Rcpp::PreserveStorage> >> = {<No data fields>}, <Rcpp::NamesProxyPolicy<Rcpp::Vector<19, Rcpp::PreserveStorage> >> = {<No data fields>}, <Rcpp::RObjectMethods<Rcpp::Vector<19, Rcpp::PreserveStorage> >> = {<No data fields>}, <Rcpp::VectorBase<19, true, Rcpp::Vector<19, Rcpp::PreserveStorage> >> = {<Rcpp::traits::expands_to_logical__impl<19>> = {<No data fields>}, <No data fields>}, cache = {
    p = 0x7fffffffbab0}}
(gdb) p x
$3 = {<Rcpp::PreserveStorage<Rcpp::Vector<16, Rcpp::PreserveStorage> >> = {
    data = 0x5555562c4360}, <Rcpp::SlotProxyPolicy<Rcpp::Vector<16, Rcpp::PreserveStorage> >> = {<No data fields>}, <Rcpp::AttributeProxyPolicy<Rcpp::Vector<16, Rcpp::PreserveStorage> >> = {<No data fields>}, <Rcpp::NamesProxyPolicy<Rcpp::Vector<16, Rcpp::PreserveStorage> >> = {<No data fields>}, <Rcpp::RObjectMethods<Rcpp::Vector<16, Rcpp::PreserveStorage> >> = {<No data fields>}, <Rcpp::VectorBase<16, true, Rcpp::Vector<16, Rcpp::PreserveStorage> >> = {<Rcpp::traits::expands_to_logical__impl<16>> = {<No data fields>}, <No data fields>}, cache = {
    p = 0x7fffffffba10}}

(gdb) p R_PV(x)
'R_PV' has unknown return type; cast the call to its declared return type

(gdb) p x->data
$5 = (SEXP) 0x5555566d2308
(gdb) p R_PV(x->data)
'R_PV' has unknown return type; cast the call to its declared return type
```

**Edit**: Here`s the source code of the function:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
List rcpp_hello_world() {

    CharacterVector x = CharacterVector::create( "foo", "bar" )  ;
    NumericVector y   = NumericVector::create( 0.0, 1.0 ) ;
    List z            = List::create( x, y ) ;

    return z ;
}
```

Comment: The R API is for C types defined by R.  You are pointing it a C++ type.  You have two options: a) convert the C++ type to a `SEXP` via `Rcpp::wrap()`.  Or b) point _inside_ the C++ type accessing the `SEXP` it contains.  PS Screenshots are mostly frowned-upon at StackOverflow.  You could have copied and pasted what you are showing there...

Comment: Yes, screen shots are bad (just a teaser ;-) The code is the original code as created by RStudio (linked in my first sentence of the question).

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel `Rcpp::wrap` and `Rcpp::print` fail in `gdb` (not found, eg. when trying `call print(x->data)` or `call Rcpp::wrap(x)`) because the linker optimizes away all unused template instances (`wrap` may also be inlined). How could I use these functions in `gdb` if my code does not use it (is there a Rcpp best practice to debug in `gdb` using these functions)?

Comment: Yes. The debugger only know C code. So it allows you to peek into a SEXP, and/or use the tools you found work with SEXP types.  Now use `as<>()` and especially `wrap()` to _create yourself a `SEXP`_.  And yes. It may require recompiling,  But as they say, "life's a b%tch and then you die".  You'll be my hero if you come with better tools at the gdb level.

Comment: BTW my current **workaround** (as you have mentioned as option b in your first comment): What always seems to work in `gdb` (without recompilation) is using the SEXP inside the C++ type, eg. `call Rf_PrintValue(x->data)`...

Comment: Precisely.  There is a `SEXP` in there, and `Rf_PrintValue` knows how to handle.  And now, I am afraid, there is no man left behind the curtain....

Comment: For anyone else who comes here and gets stuck with calling `Rf_PrintValue` in order to see the contents of a NumericVector in gdb (unknown return type)  this might help: `call (double) Rf_PrintValue(y.data)`

Comment: @FXQuantTrader I wrote a little helper package for myself to ease debugging: https://github.com/aryoda/R_CppDebugHelper

Answer (score 1):

> `(gdb) p R_PV(x)`

In my `R` source, `R_PV` is a function returning `void`. Try this instead:

```
(gdb) call R_PV(x)
```

As Dirk Eddelbuettel noted, you still need to pass the right type to `R_PV`, so perhaps the correct command is:

```
(gdb) call R_PV(Rcpp::wrap(&x))
```

Comment: THX, good starting point but I still get `a syntax error in expression...`. Learning the `gdb` syntax and pitfalls is not easy...

Comment: How can I call `wrap` if gdb says: `call Rcpp::wrap(x)` -> `No symbol "wrap" in namespace "Rcpp"`? I also tried using ... `&x`...

Comment: The template function `wrap` is optimized away since it is not used in my example code... See https://stackoverflow.com/a/24958777